# Adding a DateInterval of a day to a DateTime Object adds two days

Tags: php, date, datetime

I got two DateTime Objects like the following (Output of print_r):

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-04-01 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-04-01 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Afterwards i add a DateInterval like

```
$step = new DateInterval('P1D');
$startPointer->add($step);
$endPointer->add($step);
```

Now i got

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-04-03 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-04-03 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Why did PHP add 2 Days instead of 1?

Comment: [Example #3: beware of adding months](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: He is not adding months but days. And above code returns [date] => 2015-04-02 00:00:00.000000 for me.

Comment: Like this https://eval.in/333030

Comment: @krzysiej and what about this kind a scenario [https://eval.in/333116](https://eval.in/333116)

Comment: @Uchiha you added 1 day twice so result is still correct

Comment: @krzysiej yep I know that so its might be some that kinda scenario that could happen over here

Comment: Thank you all very much @t11n had the right suggestion in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the second of April for me, too. Despite the fact that it is the April 1st we are talking about, my assumption is that you did not clone the Date object, but referenced it a second time. So startPoint and endPoint are actually the same objects. Calling add() on each of them makes PHP add one day twice to the same object.

May this be the case?